# Proof Cantor set is uncountable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm trying to prove the cantor set is uncountable. This is what I ended up with:

We know that $[0,1]$ is uncountable. Then, after taking out the middle third, we end up with $[0, \frac{1}{3}] \cup [\frac{2}{3},1]$. Let's focus on $[0, \frac{1}{3}]$. $[0, \frac{1}{3}]$ is also uncountable. (By defining $f: [0, \frac{1}{3}] \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that for $b \in [0, \frac{1}{3}], f(b) = 3b$)

Now, if we repeat this process and take out the middle third, we end up with $[0, \frac{1}{9}] \cup [\frac{2}{9}, \frac{1}{3}]$. Let's now focus on $[0, \frac{1}{9}]$, that is also uncountable. We can keep repeating this process indefinitely, and also for $[\frac{2}{3},1]$. This way, if we then take the cantor set $C$, $C$ is the union of these sets, which are uncountable. Thus, $ C $ is uncountable.

I feel something is not entirely right with this proof, but I can't figure out what. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: $C$ is the *intersection* of the sets you are left with, not their union. Though each of those is indeed uncountable, the infinite intersection of uncountable sets can be empty, finite, countable, or uncountable.

Comment: Cantor set is the intersection of all those sets, not union. You can either construct a bijection between cantor set and base 3 decimals, or use the compact complete metric space are uncountable theorem.

Comment: @TychusFindlay May I ask, why intersection? Isn't the set defined by the disjoint union of those remaining thirds, that get progressively smaller with each step?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin May I ask, why intersection? Isn't the set defined by the disjoint union of those remaining thirds?

Comment: @TychusFindlay You seem to miss some condition. There are both finite and countably infinite compact complete metric spaces (finite sets with discrete metric or $\{1/n \ : \ \mathbb{N}\}\cup\{0\}$ as subspace of $[0,1]$).

Comment: No the cantor set is the points remaining after you remove all the open intervals, the end points of the closed intervals are not removed and they are countable, but a lot of points are not end points and are still not removed.

Comment: No, the Cantor set is defined as the intersection of the sets $C_n$, where $C_0=[0,1]$, and $C_{n+1}$ is the set obtained from $C_n$ by removing the middle third from each interval piece. See e,g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set?wprov=sfti1). The Cantor set does not contain any nontrivial interval.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Yes I can't remember the theorem, there's something that says a metric space satisfying some conditions must be uncountable. A purely topological proof of uncountability of cantor set is possible, without base 2 decimal, or base 3 decimal. I think the condition is compact, complete, and every point is not isolated, might be wrong.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oh, I see. Thanks!

Comment: @TychusFindlay I understand. Thanks!

Comment: Note that because after each removal you get a subset of your previous set, if you take the union you just get $[0,\frac{1}{3}]\cup[\frac{2}{3},1]$.

Comment: @TychusFindlay I think we wish to require that the metric space has no isolated points and is complete (if I remember correctly) for your conclusion to hold.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Yep this is it https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2523793/show-that-a-complete-metric-space-without-isolated-points-is-uncountable, no compactness required. However the base 3 decimal proof is better, because it shows cantor set has continuum cardinality, rather than simply uncountable (I think continuum hypothesis is very false).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The cantor set is uncountable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1269425/the-cantor-set-is-uncountable)

Comment: @OliverDíaz I was trying to avoid ternary representation. Thanks!

Comment: @Rararat: OK then. I laid in a rather informal way a procure to associate to each element $x$ of the Cantor set $C$ a sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s based on the location of $x$in each step of the construction of $C$.

Comment: @TychusFindlay That particular proof/result may be suboptimal, but it is provable that a complete metric space with no isolated points has cardinality of the continuum.

Comment: Note that each of $[0,1], [0,\frac12], [0,\frac13],\ldots$ is uncountable, but their intersection is finite.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to associate to each element of the Cantor set $C$ an infinite sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s and vice versa that resembles the construction of the OP. Most of the details (the intersection of nested compact sets with diameter decaying to $0$ is a point, and the like) are left to the OP.

- Notice that at each step of the construction of the Cantor set, say step $n$, a middle interval is removed from each of the $2^{n-1}$ subintervals obtained in the $n-1$-th step.
- Thus, if $I_{k,n-1}$, $k=1,\ldots, 2^{n-1}$, counted from left to right, is one subinterval obtained in the $n-1$-th step, in the $n$-step one removes the middle interval from $I_{k,n-1}$ leaving  a subinterval $I_{k',n}$ interval to the left of the middle and another $I_{k'',n}$ to the right of the middle.
- Let is denote with $0$ and $1$ left and right of middle respectively.
- Each subintervals obtained in the $n$-th step can be *codified* uniquely with a string of $0$ and $1$'s of length $n$, and conversely each string of length $n$ of $0$'s and $1$'s correspond to one (and only one) of the subintervals left on the $n$-th step of the construction.
- For example $00$ corresponds to first choosing the left subinterval at step 1 of the construction, and then from this subinterval one choses the left subinterval in step 2, that is, the subinterval $[0,1/9]$. Similarly, $01$ stands for $[3/9,1/3]$.
- Denote by  $I^n_{\iota}$, $\iota\in\{0,1\}^n$ the subinterval obtained in the $n$-step which is codified by the string $\iota$. $C=\bigcap_n\bigcup_{\iota\in\{0,1\}^n}I^n_{\iota}$.
- Then, each $x\in C$ can be associated with one (and only one) sequence $\ell=(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ of $0$'s and $1$'s which describes for each $n$, the precise subinterval  $I^n_\iota$ ($\iota=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$) in the $n$-th step $x$ belongs.
- This association is a bijection $C\rightarrow\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$. This implies that $C$ is not countable.

Answer (score 0):

Show there exists a bijection between the Cantor set and the set of sequences with entries 0 or 1. Then you can show this latter set is uncountable by doing something closely related to Cantor’s diagonal argument which proves (0,1) is uncountable.

Comment: The OP isn't asking for a proof. They are asking for feedback on their specific attempt.